# Saving an xml file using stream results in a duplicate root elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, uwp, windows-store

So I'm attempting to open an xml file, add an XElement to the root element, and save it. Except my C# Code:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("UserPinouts.tpack", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    doc.Root.Add(new XElement(XElement.Parse(CurrentPinOut)));
    doc.Save(stream);

    Debug.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
    stream.Flush();
}
```

Gives me the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RootElement>
    <XElement1/>
</RootElement>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RootElement>
    <XElement1/>
    <XElement2/>
</RootElement>
```

Instead of just that second part. I've tried changing the way I add the XElement, but I get this everytime, so I'm guessing it must be a problem with the way I open/close the stream. How could I fix this?

Comment: It is unclear what do you ask. Can you explain your issue in more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reset stream position to the beginning, just before calling `Save()` method :

```
stream.Position = 0;
doc.Save(stream);
```

I have seen this solved similar problem in old Windows Phone questions. These are some of them : 1. [Appending new XElement adds an entire XML to existing xml in stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085366/appending-new-xelement-adds-an-entire-xml-to-existing-xml-in-stream?rq=1), 2. [updating an existing xml file in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056346/updating-an-existing-xml-file-in-windows-phone)